Azure SQL Elastic Pool Scalability Problem
I am a consultant on a project that has an elastic pool for multiple databases. Right now the pool is using Standard pricing with 100 DTUs. We are experiencing a lot of issues with the Sql client and timeouts. I've attached a picture of the resource utilization over the past seven days.
This is a Blazor Server application that uses EF Core and distributed SQL Server cache.
We have three databases in this pool. One is the distributed cache and that seems to be the one hogging the resources.
My question is what is the best method here to improve the scalability of the pool? Do we switch to the vCore pricing model or just increase the DTUs? We have major issues when ~100 people try to reach the site at the same time.


What is the resource consumption contributing to high DTU usage? Please see on Azure Portal, what the Query Performance Insight section is outlining as the top queries in terms of IO, CPU and the top long running queries. Analyze the query plans and optimize those expensive queries.
Update statistics and defrag indexes regularly. Outdated statistics can delay the execution of queries and stored procedures and contribute to timeouts.
Set minimum and maximum of resources on each databases, setting more resources for the database you identified and less for the others.
One more thing to note is that Query Timeout is a client setting, make sure the timeout setting on the connection string are properly set.
About the best method to improve scalability, vCore allows to scale up CPU really fast without affecting the storage, but DTU does not have licensing costs.

